# LINQPad - can you run a linqpad script from the command-line?

Tags: build-automation, command-prompt, linqpad

Is there a way to run a LINQPad script from the command-prompt (no gui)?

If so, LINQPad would be handy for scripting C# and calling it from an automated build.

Comment: This is now supported as of v4.47 - see Frank's answer

Answer (score 16):

lprun from LinqPad has already arrived:

http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Yes, as of **LINQPad v4.45.05**:

`LINQPad.exe "c:\path\to\my\script.linq" -run`

To close the **LINQPad** window, be sure to call this at the end of your script:

`Process.GetCurrentProcess().CloseMainWindow();`

Answer (score 5):

The ability to run LINQPad scripts from the command lines was just added in beta version 4.47

Full documentation on the new lprun.exe utility is available on: http://www.linqpad.net/lprun.aspx