# How to call Linqpad script from batch file?

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt, linqpad

I have written some Linqpad scripts and would like to run each of them from one batch file, in other words one after another.

My question is how can I do that? I have been searching for a while now on Stack overflow but have come up short each time, this question [LINQPad - can you run a linqpad script from the command-line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172897/linqpad-can-you-run-a-linqpad-script-from-the-command-line) is the closest but the best answer only links back to the Linqpad instructions for command line scripting [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5172897/linqpad-can-you-run-a-linqpad-script-from-the-command-line).

Am i missing something or is this not possible? I dont understand what lprun.exe mentioned in the documentation should do because when i run it there is no command line interface it just opens the interface and closes again.

**For Reference**

> I have the following simple batch script written which does not do what is needed
>
> A) Because Im not sure how to write the path properly (new to command
>   line scripting)
>
> B) Im not sure how to execute the MyScript script once the LINQPad.exe has ran.

```
ECHO OFF

ECHO.
TITLE File opener

START "C:/Program Files (x86)/LINQPad4/MyScript.linq"

EXIT
```

---

**Paths:**

LINQ Scripts- C:\Documents\LINQPad Queries\MyScript.linq

LINQPad location - C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4

---

Thanks for the help.

---

***UPDATE***

I made some progress using the following script

```
ECHO OFF

ECHO.
TITLE File opener

LPRun.exe "C:/Program Files (x86)/LINQPad4/MyScript.linq" 

PAUSE
EXIT
```

I receive the following error

[image]

Comment: Try `lprun.exe  "C:/Program Files (x86)/LINQPad4/MyScript.linq"`

Comment: Thanks Frank, unfortunately it keeps telling me that Windows cannot find lprun.exe. Its strange because the lprun.exe file is located in the same directory as LINQPad i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4

Comment: So did you try specifying the full path to lprun.exe? So just like you specify the path to the .linq file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try lprun.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4\MyScript.linq"
It worked for me :)