# Execute a LINQPad query on opening it

Tags: linqpad

Is there a way by which, when I open a query in LINQPad, it executes it and puts me in the result-only view? The intended use case for this is to write small applications within LINQPad. I don't want to hit F5 and Ctrl+Shift+R every time.

The motivation for this is the recently released RegEx utility in 5.36. This is also a script that does the same.

Comment: I can partially help you - put `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^+R");` after the opening brace for `Main` to autotype Ctrl-Shift-R.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've added an `Util.OpenQuery` method to the next build:

```
public static Task<bool> OpenQuery (string queryPath, bool run = false,
                                    bool hideEditor = false, params object[] args)
```

You'll then be able to call this from the [Automator query](https://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1339/contextmenu-plugin-api):

```
void Main (System.Windows.Forms.Keys key, string currentQueryPath)
{
    if (key == (Keys.Shift | Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.F1))
        Util.OpenQuery (@"my query.linq", true, true);
}
```

This will allow you to automate up to 12 queries (with hotkeys Alt+Shift+Ctrl+ [F1-F12])

Comment: This is exactly what I want! I look forward to the next build, Joe. Thanks so much for this tool and your consistent work to make it great.

Comment: Small feature request: I would tend to forget which queries I've bound to which hotkeys eventually. Would it be possible for you to implement something similar to your optimize directive for this? I could start the query with `#LINQPad RunOnOpen` or something like that which, when I open the query would run it and another `#LINQPad HideEditor` would hide the editor? Just throwing some thoughts your way :) Thanks again.

Comment: I will also be added an "Open and Run" shortcuts to the navigate query dialog (Control+comma): https://twitter.com/linqpad/status/1113001784794992641 Will this help? Note that a #LINQPad RunOnOpen option on a query could be considered a security risk.

Comment: Yes, that would help for sure. Except for the fact that I have to remember to open it in that way. But I do get your point on it being a security risk.

Comment: A new LINQPad beta has now been released: 
https://www.linqpad.net/download.aspx#beta

Comment: YOU ARE AMAZING

Answer (score 3):

You can launch [LINQPad from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17775574/2557128) with arguments to run a script file:

```
linqpad "path to file" -run
```

Then if you add the line

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("^+R");
```

As the first line in `Main`, the code will be hidden.

Note the linked answer's suggestion for closing LINQPad at the end of the script.

Comment: Thanks for this, @NetMage. But I don't want to open a query from the commandline. I meant that I would be _inside_ linqpad and I open the query. Much like the RegEx evaluator that Joe put in the latest build :) I appreciate the answer however, I learnt about the `SendKeys` method from this.